# Как получить сумму цифр числа с учётом знака: -35 -> -3 + 5 -> 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая функция:

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(a)])
```

Для положительных чисел она возвращает корректные значения, но неверные для отрицательных. Пример: вызовем функцию для числа `-35` - должно вернуть 2, но не срабатывает, поскольку `str(a)` **знак минуса** рассматривает как отдельный символ.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В заголовке написано "сумма цифр", в примере, который вы привели `sumDigits(-35)` должно быть равно 2. Что за задача перед вами стоит, что при сумме цифр отрицательного числа первая цифра отнимается от суммы остальных? Каким вы ожидаете результат, например, от исходных чисел `-911`, `-10000`?

Comment: -9 +1 +1 = -7
-1 +0 + 0 + 0 = -1

Comment: А по поводу применимости этой задачи что-нибудь можете сказать? Зачем вычисляется такая необычная сумма?

Comment: это все codewars.com.

Я сначала решил задачу другим способом,
потом нагуглил этот, но с ошибкой.
В python я новичок, думаю переходить c php на python

Comment: Но если мой вариант сработал на тестах codewars.com, значит минус не должен влиять на первую цифру (в смысле ее тоже нужно прибавлять)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, например, считать сумму цифр абсолютного значения

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(abs(number))])
```

Comment: спасибо, работает !

Comment: @gudfar: код в данном ответе возвращает `8` для `-35`, а не `2` как вопросе указано. Другие ответы пытаются учесть наличие знака в числе.

Comment: в сторону: квадратные скобки `[]`  здесь не нужны: `sum(int(digit) for digit in str(abs(number)))` или `sum(map(int, str(abs(number))))`

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверять может ли каждый символ в строке быть интерпретирован как число

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(number) if i.isdigit()])
```

В такую функцию можно даже передать не число, результатом будет сумма всех цифр в строке

```
>>> sumDigits('-123 строка')
6
```

**Обновлено**

Если всё же надо учитывать знак минус при сложении, то вот такой вариант на регулярных выражениях

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return sum([int(x) for x in re.findall('(?:-)?\d', str(number))])


>>> sumDigits('-123')
4
```

Comment: по логике автора в результате `4` должно получиться. `-1 + 2 + 3`

Comment: abs нужно добавить и тогда все ок)

Comment: @slippyk что-то не сходится тогда, в принятом ответе тоже 6 выходит. andy.37 выходит прав в своём ответе

Answer (score 1):

```
def dig_sum(x):
    sx = str(x)
    if sx[0] == '+':
        return dig_sum(sx[1:])
    elif sx[0] == '-':
        return dig_sum(sx[1:]) - 2 * int(sx[1])
    else:
        return sum([int(i) for i in sx])

print dig_sum(35) --> 8
print dig_sum('+35') --> 8
print dig_sum(-35) --> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Таки сумму цифр можно считать как сумму цифр без шаманства с переводом в строку и обратно:

```
from __future__ import division

import timeit

def sum_digits(number):
    summ = 0
    ab_numb = abs(number)
    divm = divmod
    while ab_numb > 10:
        ab_numb, remainder = divm(ab_numb, 10)
        summ += remainder
    if number > 0:
        return summ + ab_numb
    else:
        return summ - ab_numb
```

Теперь сравним все решения:

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(abs(number))])

def sumDigits_eval(number):
    return eval('+'.join([i for i in str(number)]))

def sumDigits_regex(number):
    return sum([int(x) for x in re.findall('(?:-)?\d', str(number))])

print("Math: ", timeit.repeat("sum_digits(-34543)", "from __main__ import sum_digits", number=100000))
print("Str: ", timeit.repeat("sumDigits(-34543)", "from __main__ import sumDigits", number=100000))
print("Eval: ", timeit.repeat("sumDigits_eval(-34543)", "from __main__ import sumDigits_eval", number=100000))
print("Regexp: ", timeit.repeat("sumDigits_regex(-34543)", "from __main__ import sumDigits_regex", number=100000))

>>> Math:  [0.24735833889623768, 0.24581550535393623, 0.24613614212789509]
>>> Str:  [0.407044484349559, 0.4065382805822204, 0.4061474403660761]
>>> Eval:  [2.771394191096233, 2.761938895909233, 2.76689131768166]
>>> Regexp:  [0.8407116740523968, 0.837011418938836, 0.835758841733524]

print("Math: ", timeit.repeat("sum_digits(-310104588999943)", "from __main__ import sum_digits", number=100000))
print("Str: ", timeit.repeat("sumDigits(-310104588999943)", "from __main__ import sumDigits", number=100000))

>>> Math:  [0.7094168680396982, 0.7092928830131481, 0.7118370393360973]
>>> Str:  [0.9090130545558752, 0.9149762416771967, 0.9091776836805323]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще Вам один способ:

```
def sumDigits(number):
    return eval('+'.join([i for i in str(number)]))
```

P.S. Решение из ответа, который Вы пометили, как правильный, не работает.

Comment: работает, я тесты запускал

Comment: Значит у Вас условие не соответствует тестам. Попробуйте, там для -35 выдает 8, а по условию должно получится 2.

Comment: Еще у меня не хватает рейтинга, чтобы комментировать не под своими постами, поэтому тут напишу. В решении m9_psy (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542660/214570) нужно '> 10' заменить на '>=10', иначе для 1000 неверно работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumDigits(number):
    if number >= 0:
        return sum([int(i) for i in str(number)])
    else:
        number = abs(number)
        summa = sum([int(i) for i in str(number)])
        summa -= int(str(number)[0]) * 2
        return summa
```

**Вроде работает=)**